# jQuery overlay flicker

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with an image overlay where it flickers and then fades, I am assuming it has something to d with the css loading the overlay and then the jQuery triggering?

```
.Image-Overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer; 
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column xsmall-12 small-6 medium-3 overlay">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
    /img/insidePages/Layer90.jpg" alt="Kenya" />
    <div class="Image-Overlay">
        <p>content on overlay</p>
    </div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

```
$('.overlay').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).fadeIn('slow');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Really I am wanting for it slide up the overlay on hover but I have looked at the jQuery website and the effect is not working, any tips on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La2jf91t/)

```
$('.overlay').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).slideDown('fast');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).slideUp('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function instead of mouseenter/mouseleave?

```
$('.overlay').hover(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).fadeIn('slow');
}, function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

You didn't say at what point it flickers (load/ mouseover)? so I'm guessing here it's on the mouseleave.

Either way, it's one function to do what you're currently doing with two functions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $( ".overlay" ).mouseover(function() {
$('.Image-Overlay').fadeIn('slow');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for / saying, but if you quickly repeat the mouseenter / mouseleave action then the fadein / fadeout will trigger a lot of time and it will blink like hell. I suggest you to consider using the `stop` function to prevent that to happen

```
$('.overlay').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.Image-Overlay', this).stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS Animations for this effect.

```
.Image-Overlay {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 cursor: pointer; 
 color: #fff;
 box-sizing: border-box;  
 padding: 20px;

 // you can change bottom with anything else with a numeric value
 // animate out time
 transition: bottom 500ms ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: bottom 500ms ease-out;
}

.overlay:hover .Image-Overlay{
 bottom: 0;

 // animate in time
 transition: bottom 200ms ease-out;
 -webkit-transition: bottom 200ms ease-out;
}
```

this would looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwrj6y31/1/